# Undo excel column sort

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

By mistake I sorted a column in an excel document and I saved the file. Is there any way to revert to the original data in the file or restore the file to last day's state ?

It was a lot of edited data and I currently have mixed data with that column out of sync with other columns in all rows. I basically wan't to revert to the original order of that column as of yesterday.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer right-click the file and select Restore previous versions. Then select an earlier version of your file.